# How can I insert odd and even number in attribute table for selected feature in Arc Map?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I work with addressing, in right site of street must be inserted even number, and in left site of street must be inserted odd number in attribute table. Is there any code to insert odd and even number spontaneously from field calculator?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear, are you manually selecting the sides of the streets? If so select the odd's and use Field Calculator.

[image]

Pre-logic

```
a = iter(range(1,9999,2))
def odd():
   return next(a)
```

Call with

```
odd()
```

For even change to `a = iter(range(2,9999,2))`

Comment: Nice! @MZia if this answered your question could you accept it with the checkbox?

Comment: @BERA, how would you control ordering with that method?

Comment: @Andy what do you mean by ordering? OP does not ask for any specific order, just odd or even numbers

Comment: @BERA true: the OP did not ask. But normally, address ranges ascend/descend in order along each side of the road. So I wonder in which order `odd()` is applied: database row order? the order in which the features were selected? Is it predictable? I tried a quick test and got an unpredictable result.

Comment: I agree, some order would make more sense. Seems to be by the order of the feature class. It would be possible to rewrite the function to order from top-bottom etc.